# Positioning images inside an SVG container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, gsap

Please help)
I have a small animation:

```js
"use strict";
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

let timeline = gsap.timeline({
  repeat: 2, 
  repeatDelay: 5, 
  defaults: {duration: 12, ease: "power1.inOut"}
})

  .to("#hand", {
    motionPath: {
      path:"#path", 
      align:"#path", 
      alignOrigin:[0.28, 0.08]}
  })

  .to("#path", {strokeDasharray: "4046, " + "0"}, "<");  

document.getElementById("pause").onclick = () => timeline.pause();
document.getElementById("play").onclick = () => timeline.play();
document.getElementById("reverse").onclick = () => timeline.reverse();
document.getElementById("seek").onclick = () => timeline.seek(5);
document.getElementById("restart").onclick = () => timeline.restart();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<svg height="600" width="900">
  <circle cx="325" cy="480" r="3"/>
    <image id="hand" xlink:href="https://github.com/avturin1980/GSAP/blob/main/C2L6/hand.png?raw=true" x="325" y="480"/>
    <path id="path" d="M364.5,493.5c-109,26-197.9-28.2-243.4
    -92.6-2.3-3.2-13.4-17.9-11.6-21.4,3.8-7.5,21.7,1.4,27.7,
    3.4,11.3,3.9,70.1,20.6,68.3,36.5-2.5,23-54.1-27.9-58.8
    -34-8.3-10.9-47.6-83.9-7.5-71.4,10.2,3.2,26.9,24.9,21.2,
    35.8-8.2,15.7-20.5,1.3-21-10.5-2-40.1,51.1-64.8,78.2-81.2,
    29.1-17.5,63.8-26.9,91-46.5,29.7-21.5,49.1-53.5,74.8-79.2,
    12.1-12.1,38.3-46.2,50.3-25.3,10.2,17.6-5.2,39.4,12,56.4,
    10.8,10.6,31.5,11.3,37.1,26.8,4.5,12.6-12.4,27.3-4.1,37.7
    s31.4,2.9,40.5-1.9c17-9.1,67-65.8,80.1-26,9.6,29.1-23.5,
    55.7,13.1,78.8,24.4,15.3,62.5,18.1,90.4,15.5,30.3-2.8,85.6
    -25.9,74.2-67.4-10.5-38.1-69.7-6.1-86.3,7.7-29.3,24.4-50.9,
    71.4-27.6,106.3,20.1,30.2,63.9,46.3,98.2,34.9,46.6-15.4,
    24.5-50.5-13.1-59.3-41.8-9.7-79.9,11.2-112.5,35.6C620.1,
    363.9,606,377.5,591,390c-6.7,5.7-42,20.6-30-2,15.3-28.9,
    77.9,23.5,86.3,39.6,24.1,46.8-30.5,72.5-68.2,57.1-12.6-5.2
    -25-14.2-33.2-25.2-5.5-7.3-23.1-51.1.1-51.5,16.6-.3,4.6,
    31.2.1,37.2-9.3,12.4-28.5,20.5-42.3,26.4-25,10.8-58.1,13.4
    -84.8,10.5-21.1-2.3-79.8-36.1-38.9-56.3,26.7-13.1,76.4,12.9,
    94.1,32.9,20.6,23.2,32.3,69.9-6.4,82.5-36.7,12.1-77.1-25.1
    -99.6-49.2-17-18.2-34.8-44.1-56.9-56.8-10.7-6.2-39.1-7.5
    -29.8,10.8s40.9,7.4,51.6-.1c29.9-21,29.3-64.6,23.2-97-6.9
    -36.6-37-62-72.9-67.5-42.2-6.5-80.3,12.2-89.7,55.8-6.2,28.9,
    7.7,84.4,48.9,66.7,34-14.7,10.5-71.9-21.8-55.7-12.9,6.4-18,
    25.5-4.8,34.8,9.3,6.5,29.6,1,25-13-2.9-8.8-18.5-11.6-22-2
    -5.2,14.4,21.4,3.7,6,3" fill = "none" 
    stroke = "blue" stroke-width = "4" stroke-dasharray="0 4046"/>
</svg>

<button id="pause">pause</button>
<button id="play">play</button>
<button id="reverse">reverse</button>
<button id="seek">seek</button>
<button id="restart">restart</button>
```

```
[https://codepen.io/AlexandrTyurin/pen/LYLOGjy][1]
```

About 20 percent of the time (after a page reload) the marker misses the line.
I found that the picture with the hand and the felt-tip pen is placed with a shift, and not at the desired point. For control, I drew a dot in the place where I place my picture x="325" y="480".
This problem occurs, with about the same frequency as in the case of local placement of files and in codepen.
What do you advise to do with this?
[image]

Comment: Try launching the animation after the image is loaded, for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete and see if it solves your issue

Comment: Please dont link to external code sources. Create a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead to show your code.

Comment: Inserted snippet. Waiting for all page resources to load doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by **specifying the dimensions** of the image of the hand with the marker.

```
<image id="hand" xlink:href="https://github.com/avturin1980/GSAP/blob/main/C2L6/hand.png?raw=true" x="325" y="480" width="145" height="186"/>
```